# VSCode : Unable to open file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

> Unable to open file ... Cannot read file ...

I keep getting the error whenever i use `Command+P` to open a file by name on my mac. The structure of the project has changes many times these last days. How can i re-run the projects path generation for VSCODE?

I tried rebuilding the code, but i am not sure exactly when or if VSCode rebuilds its internal file paths.

Could it be a problem with my extensions? I mean it keep referring to files/paths that WERE there earlier, but are not there now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clear the file content cache in Visual Studio Code, open the command palette:

- For Mac: ⇧⌘P or  F1
- On Windows and Linux: Ctrl + Shift + P

and type command:

```
Clear Editor History
```

Press Enter